# WMS Server GetMap returns white image

Tags: wms, getmap

I want to download a tiff image from this WMS server with the GetMap-Method:

*http://services.lgrb-bw.de/index.phtml?SERVICE_NAME=lgrb_corg&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.1&SERVICE=WMS*

After searching for answer, especially here on Stackexchange I managed to write this request and could download the image: *http://www4.lgrb.uni-freiburg.de/serverbase/services/index.phtml?SERVICE_NAME=lgrb_corg&amp&request=GetMap&service=WMS&version=1.1.1&layers=cg004&format=image%2Ftiff&STYLE=default&SRS=EPSG:4326&bbox=6.83803,47.2802,8.0206,48.9963&width=2048&height=2048*.

But unfortunately the map is completely white. Any suggestions what could be the reason?

Comment: The WMS 1.3.0 response tells us in terms of min and max scale denominators like `<MinScaleDenominator>7500</MinScaleDenominator>` and `<MaxScaleDenominator>125000</MaxScaleDenominator>`

Comment: You may also need to take into account the WMS/WMTS standard size for a pixel of 0.28 x 0.28 mm (or approx 91 dpi)

Answer (score 1):

If you checkout the [`GetCapabilities` response](http://services.lgrb-bw.de/index.phtml?SERVICE_NAME=lgrb_corg&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.1&SERVICE=WMS&request=getcapabilities) you will see the layers have a `ScaleHint` set

```
<ScaleHint min="3.74177136322228" max="62.3628560537046" />
```

this means you will only get a response at scales between 1:3.7 and 1:62 (in the "native" projection of [EPSG:31467](https://epsg.io/31467)). From a quick experiment in QGIS it looks as though you'll get responses from about 1:75K to 1:5K in EPSG:4326.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint!
I also tried to consider the scale with this request:
http://www4.lgrb.uni-freiburg.de/serverbase/services/index.phtml?SERVICE_NAME=lgrb_corg&amp&request=GetMap&service=WMS&version=1.1.1&layers=cg004&format=image%2Ftiff&STYLE=default&SRS=EPSG:31467&bbox=3345000,5240000,3447400,5342400&width=2048&height=2048

As far as I understand I am now requesting a map with 1 pixel equal to 50 m, so I should be on the given scale between 3.74 and 62.4 but all I see is still blank.

Am I right or did I miss something?